Getting 400 when trying to download sharepoint file using python and 365 clinet
I am trying to download sharepoint file using office 365 python clinet and user credentials. But I am getting following error when trying download. But I am able to list down the files without any issues. Here's my code.
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext,UserCredential
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File
import logging

url = "https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/"
username= "xxxxxx@xxxxxx.org"
password= "xxxxxxxx"

ctx = ClientContext(url).with_user_credentials(username, password)

file_url = "https://xxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxxxx/Shared Documents/Public/xxxxxx.pdf"
response = File.open_binary(ctx, file_url)

print(response)
with open("./xxxxxx.pdf", "wb") as local_file:
    local_file.write(response.content)

Alternatively I've tried this method but I'm getting 404 error in there as well.
context = ClientContext(url).with_user_credentials(username, password)

response = File.open_binary(context, '/'.join(['/sites/xxxxx/Shared Documents/Public', 
                                           'xxxxx.pdf']))

print(response)

I'm not getting any python error here is the reponse as the requested.
b'{"error":{"code":"-2130575338, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The file /sites/xxxx/Shared Documents/Public/xxxxxx.pdf does not exist."}}}'


always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

context = ClientContext(f"{url}/sites/XXXX").with_user_credentials(username, password)
file_url = f'/sites/xxxxx/Public/xxxxx.pdf'
file = File.open_binary(context, file_url)

Above method is working
